# What does these Cassandra warnings mean: Unable to lock JVM memory and MemoryMeter uninitialized

Tags: cassandra

I'm getting the following warnings on [Cassandra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cassandra) - what does it mean? And is it an issue?
And how can I solve this?

> WARN 15:32:06,772 Unable to lock JVM memory (ENOMEM). This can result in part of the JVM being swapped out, especially with mmapped I/O enabled. Increase RLIMIT_MEMLOCK or run Cassandra as root.
>
> WARN 15:33:20,860 MemoryMeter uninitialized (jamm not specified as java agent); assuming liveRatio of 10.0.  Usually this means cassandra-env.sh disabled jamm because you are using a buggy JRE; upgrade to the Sun JRE instead

I'm using Cassandra 1.1.2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ENOMEM is a Linux Error code for [`Out Of Memory`](http://wlug.org.nz/ENOMEM). Cassandra has used all its virtual memory so the JVM can't lock additional memory resource from the virtual memory.

[`Jamm`](https://github.com/jbellis/jamm/) (Java Agent for Memory Management) provided MemoryMeter. What I see is that you don't have MemoryMeter installed and setup as an agent, so Cassandra disabled MemoryMeter. Also, MemoryMeter might only work for <strike>Sun</strike> Oracle JRE, and Cassandra prefers it if you want MemoryMeter to run successfully.

---

To add `Jamm` to the Java Agent, add the following argument to the java process (example):

```
-javaagent:bin/../lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar
```

(where the path is the path where the jar resides).

Comment: How can I check the installation of Jamm? I see that cassandra comes with jamm-0.2.5.jar In it's lib folder. I've checked the jdk version, it is Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)

Comment: `export JAVA_OPTIONS=-javaagent:$TITAN_HOME/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar`

Comment: A complete walkthrough for ENOMEM is here http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/troubleshooting/trblshootInsufficientResources_r.html also do not forget `sysctl -p`